# Issue with ubuntu and bluetooth mouse and keyboard

Tags: 12.04, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth

I have a bluetooth mouse & keyboard (Dell KM714) that don't seem to be recognized by Ubuntu 14.10. They don't appear in the list of bluetooth devices when I am looking for them.

Is there a way to make them work together?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Blueman?

It has many more drivers for additional devices than the normal bluetooth. `sudo apt-get install blueman` and see if using that fixes your problem.

I know that using this manager instead of the original has worked to connect my bluetooth keyboard originally designed for my iPad.

Edit: The actual solution:

The Dell KM714 Keyboard no Mouse set are not in fact Bluetooth capable. They are controlled by a wireless USB Dongle that should have come with the product.

If you do not have the USB dongle, you may not be able to use this mouse and keyboard.

Comment: blueman seems to find my apple mouse, but not the DELL one. Is it possible that this mouse is not compatible with ubuntu?

Comment: Found your problem, the keyboard and mouse are in fact a USB wireless device.

Comment: Do I need to buy something like a dongle?

Comment: I had logitek wireless keyboard, and the usb dongle was actually inside the compartment with the batteries. You might wanna check there